# How to increase the number of angular divisions in a MATLAB polar plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I would like to have a custom figure [i'm unable to post the sample image here :-( ] in matlab. Angular labels `a` to `p` is a list of values such that `a = 930`, `b= 174` .. `p=100`. It is better to get the radial labels such as 0,1000,2000 …..11000 (total 12)
Please have a look at my code:

```
t=0:1000:15000; % unable to get the 12 radial divisions. getting only 5 concentric circles.

figure();

% rho is a 1 x 16 double array containing the values of a to p.
h = polar(t,rho); 

% since polar plot by default gives the degrees such as 0,30,60,90 …, I am replacing each one with the label.
```

**I would like to have more angular divisions. for instance 4 (e-d,d-c,c-b,b-a). Please let me have your input please.**

```
set(findall(gcf, 'String', '0'),'String', ' e');
set(findall(gcf, 'String', '30'),'String', ' d');
set(findall(gcf, 'String', '60'),'String', ' c');

…………

%Changing the colour of all angular labels
anglabels = findall(gcf, 'Type', 'text', 'horizontalalignment','center');
set(anglabels,'Color','r');
```

but i am not getting the resultant image according to my requirements.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Best regards,

Lekshmi

Answer (score 0):

I have wanted to do this in the past as well, specifically for a wind rose where I wanted to have the cardinal points around the outside and with zero (north) at the top and 90 degrees (east) on the right.

Unfortunately, the code for `polar` is kind of a hack by Mathworks. If you load in `polar.m` you can see that the angles, labels, and number of rings are hard-coded in. You will always get the rings labeled on an invisible line going 8 degrees to the right of the vertical, for instance. I don't think any of the labels are addressable using `get` and `set`. After trying similar things to what you've tried here, I just ended up forking and then modifying `polar` to have the properties I needed for my particular project.

There are a few alternatives to `polar` on the [MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/), but I have not tested any of them.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! The above set function is working for me. Labels can be accessed using the set (i have tried) and get (i saw it in one code) functions. I checked the polar function. what you said is absolutely right. most of the things are hard-coded there. My minimum requirement is to have more angular divisions. Have to look for some workaround.